# Unable to scroll div in a modal

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that uses same modals to ask questions. In one modal I am able to scroll the contents but in another one, generated the same way, I am not. All scrolling works fine on desktops but not on mobile (both Safari and Chrome). I have read a lot of others posts about this problem but I haven't been to solve the problem...

This modal does scroll:

```
<div class="mod mod--info" ng-init="displayInfo('order')" style="overflow: scroll;">
    <div class="mod__loading" ng-show="!orderInfo">
        <fa name="spinner" spin></fa>
        <small>{{ 'modal.info.fetch' | translate }}</small>
    </div>
    <div class="mod__list">
        <ul>
            <li class="mod__box" ng-repeat="batch in orderInfo track by batch.batch_id" ng-show="batch.order_lines.length > 0">
                <span>
                    <label ng-show="batch['full_name']">{{ 'modal.info.batch' | translate }} {{ batch['created_at'] | amDateFormat:'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss' }}</label>
                    <small>{{ 'modal.info.by' | translate }} {{ batch['full_name'] }}</small>
                </span>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="line in batch.order_lines">
                        <label ng-bind-html="fixedLine(line)"></label>
                        <ul class="indent" ng-show="line.additions.length > 0">
                            <li ng-repeat="addition in line.additions">
                                <label>{{ addition.quantity }} x {{ addition.product }}</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="indent" ng-show="line.menu_items.length > 0">
                            <li ng-repeat="menu_item in line.menu_items">
                                <label>{{ menu_item.quantity }} x {{ menu_item.product }}</label>
                                <ul class="indent" ng-show="menu_item.additions.length > 0">
                                    <li ng-repeat="menu_item_addition in menu_item.additions">
                                        <label>{{ menu_item_addition.quantity }} x {{ menu_item_addition.product }}</label>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="button button--danger" hm-tap="close()">
    <fa name="times"></fa> {{ 'general.close' | translate }}
</div>
```

This one does not:

```
<div class="mod">
    <div class="mod__list" ng-show="$index == step" ng-repeat="q in questions track by $index">
        <div class="mod__heading">
            <h4>
                {{ product['receipt_name'] }}
                <small>
                    {{ 'modal.question.sequal' | translate }} {{ $index + 1 }}
                </small>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="mod__list-item-container">
            <div class="mod__list-item mod__list-item--dark-blue ignore-nth-child" ng-repeat="a in q['answers']" hm-tap="add(a['product'])">
                <span>
                    {{ a['product']['display_name'] }}
                    <span ng-show="a['price'] > 0" ng-bind="formatPrice(a['price'])"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mod__list-item mod__list-item--pink" hm-tap="cancel()" ng-show="parser.toBoolean(q.required)">Annuleren</div>
        <div class="mod__list-item mod__list-item--pink" hm-tap="next()" ng-hide="parser.toBoolean(q.required)">
            {{ 'modal.question.skip' | translate }} <fa name="share"></fa>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the mod__list-item-container:

```
&__list-item-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 70vh;
    overflow: scroll;
    //overflow-y: scroll;
    //-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you check that the CSS for `mod__list-item-container` actually works? The selector looks wrong. On the first example you posted, the one that works, you have the inline CSS to set the overflow, `style="overflow: scroll"`. You could try to add the same inline CSS to the second example, if it works, then the problem is with the CSS not being applied. Afterwards you can remove all the inline CSS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The css is correct, it's a sass file, that's why it looks wrong. I have tried to use inline styles in the second example, but unfortunately that didn't work either, when applying the css selector on the first example it also works fine...